# WCF authentication with username and password soap request

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I would like to authenticate request on WCF service with username and password 
the received request soap header will be like that,
what should I configure wcf service to check this username and password in database then.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2">
            <wsse:Username></wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password></wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tem:RequestForCustomsExemption>
            <customsExemptionRequest>
                <BILL_NUMBER>12583603</BILL_NUMBER>
            </customsExemptionRequest>
        </tem:RequestForCustomsExemption>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a Custom UsernamePasswordValidator extension. This article should have all of the info you need: [How to: Use a Custom User Name and Password Validator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-a-custom-user-name-and-password-validator)